# Android can not connect to openfire server org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I'm trying to connect to openfire server via android but it didn't worked.

---

**this is error**

```
    W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '192.168.3.24:5222' failed because: /218.68.250.118 exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /218.68.250.118 (port 5222) from /192.168.232.2 (port 43000) after 12000ms
W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:620)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:895)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:409)
        at com.example.chatdemo02.LoginActivity.initConnection(LoginActivity.java:60)
        at com.example.chatdemo02.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**this my code**

```
// Create the configuration for this new connection
    configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("a", "123456");
    try {
        configBuilder.setConnectTimeout(6000);
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setResource("Android");
        configBuilder.setXmppDomain("192.168.3.24");
        configBuilder.setHost("192.168.3.24");
        configBuilder.setPort(5222);
        configBuilder.setSendPresence(true);
    }catch (org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
    try {
        AndroidUsingLinkProperties.setup(getApplicationContext());
        // Connect to the server
        connection.connect();
        // Log into the server
        connection.login();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(connection.isConnected()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainpageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**My current situation**

1. my system is windows 10
2. I'm using **smack 4.3.1** and **Openfire Version: 4.3.2**
3. I have opened necessary port in firewall
4. my android and my computer is in same local area network

---

**I have been confused about this for several days.please help me**

Comment: I don't remember why, but I faced some problems with latest version of smack and I forced to downgrade my smack to 4.2.2 and everything was work OK. try to downgrade your smack may gives a chance.

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi Thanks for your reply, I have found that it was my router's problem, when I connected different router, it worked.

Comment: I am facing the same issue using Smack 4.3.4 and getting smackexception.connectionexception while connecting my chat server. When I tried to connect with Spark in windows 10 it work likes a charm but unlucky with my android smack library 4.3.4. Any suggestion or trick or help will be appreciated. I even try with another router but no luck. Please help me.